# SQL Server : comparing a table to itself

Tags: sql-server

I keep getting the same values returned when running my query, I am trying to find pairs of store ID's were their store type is the same. The table name is `STORE`.

It should only return Store ID's 412, 364, and 428 since they have the same store type but it's returning all of the values.

My code so far:

```
SELECT 
    B.STORE_ID, C.STORE ID  
FROM 
    STORE B 
INNER JOIN 
    STORE C ON B.STORE_ID = C.STORE_ID
WHERE 
    B.STORE_TYPE = C.STORE_TYPE
```

Example of Table:

```
STORE_ID    STORE_TYPE 
---------------------------
412           1
358           2
364           1
428           1
134           4
156           6
136           5
```

Please go easy on my post this is my first time asking for help on this site.

Comment: You're only joining the row with itself, because of this `B.STORE_ID = C.STORE_ID`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> pairs of store ID's were their store type is the same.

JOIN on type, look for different IDs:

```
SELECT 
    B.STORE_ID, C.STORE ID  
FROM 
    STORE B 
INNER JOIN 
    STORE C ON B.STORE_TYPE = C.STORE_TYPE 
WHERE 
    B.STORE_ID != C.STORE_ID
```